# GCC 8.3 can't compile std::bind_front

Tags: c++, compilation, standards, c++20, gcc8

is that possible that g++ somehow compile my program with older standard than I specified?

I compile with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -std=c++2a -fconcepts
```

And compiler can't recognize bind_front function ( I included `<functional>` ). Compiler version is GCC 8.3.

Comment: Please show the full error output (I suspect you need a `std::`)

Comment: What is your GCC version? GCC 9.2 with -std=c++2a flag compiles successfully

Comment: I got std as well.

Comment: And please show us a [mcve] of your code that replicates the error.

Comment: I don't have my pc now. So I can't chec g++ version . Bu yesterday I reinstall g++ and I think it's about 8.3

Comment: 8.3 does not support `std::bind_front`

Comment: @ziyiyituxe `std::bind_front` has been implemented only since GCC 9.1, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Comment: How can I upgrade to 9.1? I mean I tried apt- update and reinstalling. It's still 8.something(Ubuntu)

Comment: @ziyiyituxe Ubuntu probably has a specific `g++-9` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC 8.3 does not support `std::bind_front`. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:11),source:'%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+minus(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++return+a-b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+fifty_minus+%3D+std::bind_front(minus,+50)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+fifty_minus+(3)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g83,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-fconcepts',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+8.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

You need to use GCC 9.1 or 9.2. Check [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:11,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:11),source:'%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Aint+minus(int+a,+int+b)+%7B%0A++++return+a-b%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++auto+fifty_minus+%3D+std::bind_front(minus,+50)%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+fifty_minus+(3)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic+-O3+-std%3Dc%2B%2B2a+-fconcepts',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4).

[How to install GCC 9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140183/install-gcc-9-on-ubuntu-18-04)

**UPDATE**

As the [@walnut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11941443/walnut)'s comment says, there is a g++ 9 package in the standard repositories since Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: The answers in the linked question seem slightly out-of-date. There seems to be a g++-9 package in the standard repositories since Ubuntu 19.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/disco/g++-9

Comment: I've got ubuntu 19.04, i have apt updated and isntalled g++. When i type ```g++ --version``` its still 8.3, how is that posible? / I want to compile with g++ comand as default g++9 )

Comment: @ziyiyituxe Have you followed the instructions from the link I provided?

Comment: yes I used this commands ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc-9``` and I can compile with g++-9 but i need g++ to be -9 by default

Comment: @ziyiyituxe try this `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-9 60 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-9`